# Using Voice instead of 'raw_input' in python for Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I'm in the process of making a Python-based personal assistant/question answerer, which, in my wildest dreams, will rival the inevitable "Siri For Mac". However, as of now, it requires you type text into an infinite loop of raw_inputs, and processes the text each time. But if this is ever to be useful to, well, people, it can't be a .py in a terminal window. As of now, I'm thinking about making it a simple .app with Platypus.  But, since there is no text input on the Window app style for Platypus, I would include no GUI, and just have it all be speech-based, for input and output.  Output is simple, I can just replace all 'print' lines with 'speakString' from "macspeech". But input would be the tricky part.  I can only find libraries to input speech on Windows (pyspeech is EXACTLY what I need, but it's windows-based). Anyone heard of something like pyspeech for mac/universal?

Comment: since OS X's "Speakable Items" utility is integrated with Automator, you might be able to find a Python module that either talks with it directly or can run an Automator script that prompts for voice input. But then you'd be stuck with "Speakable Items", which wasn't very great last time I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at [Sphinx4.0 from CMU](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/).

Sadly, it is written in Java. I think the recognition is better than what is built into my mac. I am just learning java/python so am struggling with getting the two to talk to each other.

You can interface with the mac speech engine using `Appkit.NSSpeechRecognizer`:

```
from Foundation import *
```

The final method is to use the google voice search. But that requires shipping a voice snippet to the "cloud".

That approach is the most accurate but takes up to 10 seconds for a reply!